# Windows 2008: SQL Management studio, can't connect remotely with firewall enabled, but i have TCP 1433 enabled

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, firewall

I have setup SQL Server express R2 on WIndows Server 2008 R2 and i can connect locally with SQL Management studio.

Remotely with the firewall enabled i cannot connect.

If i disable the firewall then remotely i can connect.

THis is very strange.

My firewall setting is set to TCP 1433 (although i also added 1434 as well)... but it refuses to work.

In the SQL Express R2 i have TCP/IP Enabled and it listens on 1433

Any help really appreciated, i am little lost. I have searched the net and i believe i am doing everything correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the permissions to connect both sql server to and database?

Comment: well if i disable the firewall i can connect without an issue.  I am using sa ... infact i am using the exact same settings... all i do is disable the firewall and it works ... enable the firewall and it won't let me through.

Comment: This brings an assumption that there may be a rule that actually denies SQL port (could be named "Block MSDE", for example). I assume is it Windows Firewall not 3rd party? Maybe (just maybe) the rule that enabled SQL Server port is enabled only to certain Profile?

Answer (score 1):

Have you restarted the SQL service since you made the configuration changes to enable TCP/IP and set a static port? These changes will not take effect until the service is restarted.

You can verify what ports are being listened on by using netstat -a on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Add these ports:

TCP 1433, 1434, 1444
UDP 1434

To be honest, I don't remember how I found these, or if I had to do anything to SQL (I don't think I did), but I took these from a SonicWALL I set up to do just what you are trying to accomplish, and it works.

Make sure you do it on both the hardware firewall and local software firewall.